# Account The workflow could not copy the item. Make sure the source and destination lists have the same columns and column settings

Tags: list

I am getting below error while Approving sharepoint list item. It's not for all items. Only for few items I'm getting this issue.

> Account The workflow could not copy the item. Make sure the source and
>   destination lists have the same columns and column settings.

Comment: whats the logic written in your workflow?

Comment: Are you copying the item somewhere else after approval?

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure the person approving the item have enough rights on the list. If you are using a task list, approver would require contribute permission on it, else how would he be able to modify the status of the task.